# Run spark cluster using an independent YARN (without using Hadoop's YARN)

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I want to deploy a spark cluster with YARN cluster manager.
This spark cluster needs to read data from an external HDFS filesystem belonging to an existing Hadoop ecosystem that also has its own YARN (However, I am not allowed to use the Hadoop's YARN.)

My Questions are -

- Is it possible to run spark cluster using an independent YARN, while still reading data from an outside HDFS filesystem?
- If yes, Is there any downside or performance penalty to this approach?
- If no, can I run Spark as a standalone cluster, and will there be any performance issue?

Assume both the spark cluster and the Hadoop cluster are running in the same Data Center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> using an independent YARN, while still reading data from an outside HDFS filesystem

Yes. Configure the `yarn-site.xml` to the necessary cluster and use full FQDN to refer to external file locations such as `hdfs://namenode-external:8020/file/path`

> any downside or performance penalty to this approach

Yes. All reads will be remote, rather than cluster-local. This would effectively be similar performance degradation as reading from S3 or other remote locations, however.

> can I run Spark as a standalone cluster

You could, or you could use Kubernetes, if that's available, but both are pointless IMO, if there's already a YARN cluster (with enough resources) available

Comment: Thank you. In the example of the external file location, you have given the file path, e.g. `/file/path`. However, actual file locations can keep changing, or new files can get added. Does it mean that I will need to update the connection configuration all the time?

Comment: That was just an example. You'd put that literal path in the code, somehow. It is not part of config. You can also use Hadoop `FileSystem` class to list directories if the file paths are more dynamic. Doesn't change the answer that you still need to set `hdfs://namenode:port` address at the minimum to refer to the HDFS cluster